# ¿Cual es la diferencia de añadir (o no) un array en la definición de parámetros de un controlador en AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Para pasar datos desde el `controller` al `view` en AngularJS usamos lo siguiente:

**Angular Scope**

```
var x = angular.module("myApp",[]);
x.controller('myController',function($scope) {
    $scope.var1 = "valor1";
    $scope.varN = "valorN";
});
```

Recibiendo únicamente los valores contenidos dentro del ambito `$scope`.

---

En la documentación oficial de `AngularJS`(anexo al final) haciendo referencia al servicio `$window`(objeto global de JavaScript), usan la siguiente configuración:

**Angular + Javascript(Window) scope**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
x.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.var1 = "var1";
      $scope.varN = "varN";
      $scope.var1JS = $window.var1JS;
      $scope.var2JS = $window.var2JS;
  }]);
```

Recibiendo valores de los ambitos `$scope` y `$window`.

---

¿Por que razón utilizan un array con los dos scopes (`$scope`,`$window`) a demás de la función por defecto en los parámetros del `controller`, si es posible que funcione únicamente pasando el parámetro `$window` de manera adicional?, de esta manera:

```
let myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.controller("myController",function($scope,$window) {
    $scope.var1 = "valor1";
    $scope.varN = "valorN";
    $scope.var1Js=$window.var1Js;
    $scope.var2Js=$window.var2Js;
});
```

**Suponiendo** desde el primer método que si el controlador reconoce el servicio `$scope` de forma predeterminada, también podría hacerlo con `$window`.

*Anexo:* https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se usa un array como parametro en los controladores para que angular pueda identificar que servicios injectar cuando se comprime/ofusca el codigo javascript.

Si comprimimos el primero, angular no podra indentificar los servicios especificados en el constructor de la funcion y lanzara un error:

```
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);myApp.controller("myController",function(r,a){r.var1="valor1",r.varN="valorN",r.var1Js=a.var1Js,r.var2Js=a.var2Js});
```

Mientras que si comprimimos/ofuscamos el siguiente codigo, angular sabe que servicios injectar por medio los nombres de los servicios que especificados en el array:

```
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);x.controller("myController",["$scope","$window",function(r,a){r.var1="var1",r.varN="varN",r.var1JS=a.var1JS,r.var2JS=a.var2JS}]);
```

Donde:
parametro `r = $scope`
parametro `b = $window`

Comment: Entonces, porque al solo añadir los parametros directamente funciona correctamente?

Comment: Porque es lo mismo que utilizar el array.